# Laravel Eloquent: Count items model relationship

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and the Eloquent class. I have three models.

City.php:

```
public function itineraries() {
    return $this->has_many('Itinerary', 'city_id');
}
```

Itinerary.php:

```
public function city()
    return $this->belongs_to('City');
}

public function type()
{
    return $this->belongs_to('Itinerarytype');
}
```

Itinerarytype.php:

```
public function itineraries()
{
    return $this->has_many('Itinerary');
}
```

As you can see a city has many itineraries and an itinerary belongs to a city and an itinerary type. The itinerarytype model has many itineraries.

Using the `with()` method is it possible to get a count of itineraries grouped into itinerary type?

For instance here is what I have so far:

```
$city = City::with(array('itineraries'))->where_slug($city_slug)->first();
```

This gets the city which has that slug and all of it's itineraries.

I'd like to get a list like: (where the text is the itinerary type and the number is the count)

> ```
> History: 10
> Entertainment: 5
> Outdoor: 6
> ...
> ```

Comment: Just dropping this one: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use join and a bit of raw sql to achieve that on a performant way:

```php
$city = City::where_slug($slug)->first();
$types = ItineraryType::join('itineraries', 'itineraries.type_id', '=', 'itenerary_types.id')
    ->where('itineraries.city_id', '=', $city->id)
    ->group_by('itinerary_types.id')
    ->order_by('itinerary_count')
    ->get(array('itinerary_types.*', DB::raw('COUNT(itineraries.id) as itinerary_count')));

foreach ($types as $type) {
    print($type->label . ': ' . $type->itinerary_count);
}
```