# Eloquent Relationship Count

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with Laravel 4 and Elqouent. My Models have the following relationships implemented:

> User *belongsToMany* Role
>   Role *belongsToMany* User

I want to query for the roles and want to get the count of related users with them.

When I do the following, I have the N+1 problem:

```
$role = Role::has('users')->get()->each(function($role) {
    $role->user_count = $role->users()->count();
});
```

Is there anything I did not think about?

Comment: Combine with() and has().  FYI if you just use with() you'll get results that include users with no roles.  http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: And then I have to do the actual counting on app layer? I wanted to leave the counting for the database, as I do not need to transmit all the users.
I am looking for a way to inject a new variable `user_count` that is filled from the database.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `addSelect()` in the Query Builder, it lets you add additional properties to your queries, and you could potentially combine that with a `join()` to include a `user_count` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my appreciation of you guys helping me, neither of your solutions actually did the trick unfortunately.

I have found another [question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340316/laravel-eloquent-count-items-model-relationship) that helped me, though.

Here is the solution that is perfectly working what I wanted:

```
Role::join('assigned_roles', 'assigned_roles.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->groupBy('roles.id')
        ->orderBy('user_count', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get(['roles.*', DB::raw('COUNT(assigned_roles.id) as user_count')]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need for `belongsToMany`:

```
// Role model

// helper relation
public function usersCount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')
      ->selectRaw('count(users.id) as count')
      ->groupBy('pivot_role_id');
}

// accessor for $role->usersCount;
public function getUsersCountAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('usersCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('usersCount');

    $related = $this->getRelation('usersCount')->first();

    return ($related) ? $related->count : 0;
}
```

Then you can eager load it:

```
$roles = Role::with('usersCount')->get();

// pick one, for example
$roles->first()->usersCount; // int
$roles->last()->usersCount; // 0 if no related users were found
```

---

You current solution unfortunately is pretty bad, because it queries the db for each role.

The code above lets you fetch that count for all the roles with just a single query.
Another thing is that you don't load all the related users if not necessary, so it doesn't eat your memory (in case it would matter).

Comment: {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Owner",
    "created_at": "2014-08-01 13:41:06",
    "users_count": [
        {
            "user_count": 5,
            "id": 2,
            "username": "emma31",
            "created_at": "2014-08-01 13:41:02",
            "pivot": {
                "role_id": 1,
                "user_id": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}`
will be returned from `$roles->first()`. I think this is not optimal, as it contains a user again. And `$roles->first()->usersCount;` is bringing the browser to not be able to load anything.

Comment: It shouldn't be hanging the browser definitely. Anyway, it's supposed to work with eager loading, so you can easily attach that info to the roles, howver it's not the best in terms of performance surely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `withCount()`

```
  $companies = $this->company
                        ->with("municipality.province")
                        ->withCount("projects","users")
                        ->get();
```

this return

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "TEST",
        "fiscal_id": "0000000",
        "image_path": "/assets/icons/svg/energy.svg",
        "municipality_id": 1111,
        "telephone": null,
        "is_active": true,
        "sector": "consultancy",
        "type": "legal",
        "created_at": "2022-07-16T16:05:38.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-16T16:05:38.000000Z",
        "projects_count": 2,
        "users_count": 2,
        "image_src": "http://localhost//assets/icons/svg/energy.svg"
    }
```